# ViewModel refetching data again with distinctUntilChanged()

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, viewmodel, android-architecture-components

I have a Fragment that I want to do a fetch once on its data, I have used `distinctUntilChanged()` to fetch just once because my location is not changing during this fragment.

### Fragment

```
 private val viewModel by viewModels<LandingViewModel> {
        VMLandingFactory(
            LandingRepoImpl(
                LandingDataSource()
            )
        )
    }

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val sharedPref = requireContext().getSharedPreferences("LOCATION", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val nombre = sharedPref.getString("name", null)
        location = name!!
    }

 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        setupRecyclerView()
        fetchShops(location)
    }

 private fun fetchShops(localidad: String) {

        viewModel.setLocation(location.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).trim())
        viewModel.fetchShopList
            .observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

                when (it) {

                    is Resource.Loading -> {
                        showProgress()
                    }
                    is Resource.Success -> {
                        hideProgress()
                        myAdapter.setItems(it.data)
                    }
                    is Resource.Failure -> {
                        hideProgress()
                        Toast.makeText(
                            requireContext(),
                            "There was an error loading the shops.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
                }
            })

    }
```

### Viewmodel

```
 private val locationQuery = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun setLocation(location: String) {
        locationQuery.value = location
    }

    val fetchShopList = locationQuery.distinctUntilChanged().switchMap { location ->
        liveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO) {
            emit(Resource.Loading())
            try{
                emit(repo.getShopList(location))
            }catch (e:Exception){
                emit(Resource.Failure(e))
            }
        }
        }
```

Now, if I go to the next fragment and press back, this fires again, I know that maybe this is because the fragment is recreating and then passing a new instance of viewmodel and thats why the location is not retained, but if I put `activityViewModels` as the instance of the viewmodel, it also happends the same, the data is loaded again on backpress, this is not acceptable since going back will get the data each time and this is not server efficient for me, I need to just fetch this data when the user is in this fragment and if they press back to not fetch it again.

Any clues ?

I'm using navigation components, so I cant use .add or do fragment transactions, I want to just fetch once on this fragment when creating it first time and not refetching on backpress of the next fragment

Comment: Just to be clear: the problem is fetchShopList is being emitted more than once with the same value, or it's being re-calculated all over again?

You can check simply by placing a breakpoint where you calculate the value and debug to see it hits the breakpoint or not.

Comment: its emited again @Boda , thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

## **TL;DR**

### You need to use a LiveData that emits its event only once, even if the ui re-subscribe to it. for more info and explanation and ways to fix, continue reading.

When you go from Fragment 1 -> Fragment 2, Fragment 1 is not actually destroyed right away, it just un-subscribe from your ViewModel LiveData.

Now when you go back from F2 to F1, the fragment will re-subscribe back to ViewModel LiveData, and since the LiveData is - by nature - state holder, then it will re-emit its latest value right away, causing the ui to rebind.

What you need is some sort of LiveData that won't emit an event that has been emitted before.

This is common use case with LiveData, there's a pretty nice article talking about this need for a similar LiveData for different types of use cases, you can read it [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-arch-handling-clicks-and-single-actions-in-your-view-model-with-livedata-ab93d54bc9dc).

Although the article proposed a couple of solutions but those can be a bit of an overkill sometimes, so a simpler solution would be using the following `ActionLiveView`

```kotlin
// First extend the MutableLiveData class
class ActionLiveData<T> : MutableLiveData<T>() {

    @MainThread
    override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<T?>) {

       // Being strict about the observer numbers is up to you
       // I thought it made sense to only allow one to handle the event
        if (hasObservers()) {
            throw Throwable("Only one observer at a time may subscribe to a ActionLiveData")
        }

        super.observe(owner, Observer { data ->
            // We ignore any null values and early return
            if (data == null)  return
            observer.onChanged(data)
            // We set the value to null straight after emitting the change to the observer
            value = null
            // This means that the state of the data will always be null / non existent
            // It will only be available to the observer in its callback and since we do not emit null values
            // the observer never receives a null value and any observers resuming do not receive the last event.
            // Therefore it only emits to the observer the single action so you are free to show messages over and over again
            // Or launch an activity/dialog or anything that should only happen once per action / click :).
        })
    }

    // Just a nicely named method that wraps setting the value
    @MainThread
    fun sendAction(data: T) {
        value = data
    }
}
```

You can find more explainiation for ActionLiveData in [this link](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-arch-handling-clicks-and-single-actions-in-your-view-model-with-livedata-ab93d54bc9dc) if you want.

I would advise using the ActionLiveData class, I've been using it for small to medium project size and it's working alright so far, but again, you know your use cases better than me. :)